# Filtering rows by tag relationship, using group_concat and where

Tags: knex.js

Using Knex (and mysql db), I'm trying to filter records by tag id, e.g. `api/locations?Tag=3,4`.

### **Requirements**

A - Filter results by tag id(s)

B - Regardless of filter, *always* return concatenated array of ALL tags for the retrieved records

**Works:** For unfiltered requests, I have records returning correctly with the Tags array populated.

**Fails:** For filtered requests, the `Tags` array does not contain all tag id's. It seems to only include the specific requested tag numbers. Instead, what's needed is ALL tag id's for the Location record, if any one of those tag id's matches a requested tag id.

I suspect a sub-query needs to be implemented, but I'm getting nowhere! Below is my current state.

### **Sample tables**

**Locations**

```
id  | Title         | Description   
-----------------------------------
234 | Green Park    | abc123
235 | Smith Theatre | abc123
236 | Jane's Bar    | abc123
237 | City Hall     | abc123
```

**Locations__Tags**

```
id  | Location_id   | Tag_id   
------------------------------
1   | 234           | 1
2   | 234           | 86
3   | 235           | 2
4   | 235           | 3
5   | 235           | 75
6   | 236           | 2
7   | 236           | 3
8   | 236           | 54
9   | 237           | 1
10  | 237           | 4
```

**Tags**

```
id  | Title     
---------------
1   | Public
2   | Private
3   | Business
4   | Government
5   | Institution
54  | Bar
75  | Theatre
86  | Park
```

### Code

```
var query = knex('locations')

// Unsure of these; needed?
query.distinct('locations.id') 
query.groupBy('locations.id')

query.select(
    'locations.id',
    'locations.Title',
    knex.raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT locations__tags.Tag_id) as Tags')
)

// Question: is leftJoin correct here?
query.leftJoin(
    'locations__tags', 
    'locations__tags.Location_id', 
    'locations.id'
)

// ...

// Before return, I process Tags so it becomes a proper array ([1,2,3]), instead of string ("1,2,3").
// Pseudo code:
// result[row.id].Tags.split(',').map(Number)
```

### Output

**Works: Unfiltered request**

e.g. `api/locations` (no filtering)

```
[
    {"id":234,"Title":"Green Park","Tags":"1,86"},
    {"id":235,"Title":"Smith Theatre","Tags":"2,3,75"},
    {"id":236,"Title":"Jane's Bar","Tags":"2,3,54"},
    {"id":237,"Title":"City Hall","Tags":"1,4"}
]
```

**Fails: Filtered request**

Adding a `whereIn` to filter records by tag id. This checks whether the `tag_id` matches any number in `reqTagArray`. This filtering works; records output is correctly limited by filter.

e.g. `api/locations?Tags=3,4`

```
query.whereIn('locations__tags.tag_id', reqTagArray)
```

The problem is the outputted `Tags` array does not have all tag id's for the given record. Only tag id's matching request tag id's are in the array.

```
[
    {"id":235,"Title":"Smith Theatre","Tags":"3"},
    {"id":236,"Title":"Jane's Bar","Tags":"3"},
    {"id":237,"Title":"City Hall","Tags":"4"}
]
```

**Desired filtered output:**

```
[
    {"id":235,"Title":"Smith Theatre","Tags":"2,3,75"},
    {"id":236,"Title":"Jane's Bar","Tags":"2,3,54"},
    {"id":237,"Title":"City Hall","Tags":"1,4"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use a sub-query

Someone else already answered this, but looks like they deleted it? Here's what they posted, roughly:

```
query.select(
    'locations.id',
    'locations.Title',
    // Remove this
    //knex.raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT locations__tags.Tag_id) as Tags')
)

// Use a sub-query (select within select)
query.select(knex.raw('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Tag_id) FROM locations__tags WHERE Location_id = locations.id) as Tags'))
```